# From a PDB file, how may I know which atoms have bonds between them?

Tags: proteins, pdb

Suppose I have a protein PDB file, and I want to know which atoms have bonds between them. How can this be done?

Sometimes people suggest using the `CONECT` field for that purpose. However, some PDB files do not have this field.

Example: [4OSK.pdb (Crystal structure of TAL effector reveals the recognition between asparagine and guanine)](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/4osk)

---

NOTE: I need bond information so that I can use this information to compute ForceFields along with MD simulation.

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/how-can-i-retrieve-bond-information-froma-protein-pdb-file

Comment: +1, but [we only allow 1 question/post](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5). Also, can you provide a sample from one of your actual PDB files? Generally when you are given XYZ coordinates of a molecule (e.g. a protein), we determine which atoms have bonds between them just by the distances between the atoms (perhaps depending also on the elements).

Comment: If you pretend to use only the info from the PDB (without using any other tool) you can look at the end of the file for the CONECT section.

Comment: @NikeDattani, I am looking for a general solution, a solution that can be applied to any PDB file.

Comment: @user366312 Your question would be better received and more likely to get an answer if you show a sample of one of your PDB files.

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10273/5

Comment: A bond is present when the distance between two atoms is lower than the sum of the Van der Waals radii of the two atoms. That's how most visualisation software draws bonds. Either you use some of the software to get a list of bonds (OpenBabel, Mdanalysis), or you program this yourself.

Comment: For the most recent edit, if you have a new question, you should ask it in a different post and leave this question (and any answers its already received) intact.

Comment: @Tyberius, Yesterday, I talked to a professor. He doesn't agree with the answer I posted. So, I prefered to delete the answer.

Comment: @user366312 okay, but the question remains the same. Maybe Geoff or someone else will answer your question. Another thing you can do is undelete the answer and let the community decide. This community is larger than your professor. If you are worried about your professor disagreeing with your answer, you can turn it into a "Community Wiki" so that it's just a random answer that's written by the "community" instead of you (so you won't lose any reputation if it's an incorrect answer). You can also ask to dissociate your name from the post altogether, but the answer can remain up for us to vote.

Comment: @NikeDattani, Okay, I undeleted my result and edited it also.

Comment: @user366312 Thank you! do you want us to make it a Community Wiki or to dissociate your username from the answer? Also, if your professor's criticisms can be incorporated into an edit, that might be helpful.

Comment: @NikeDattani, My professor said what I wrote in my latest edit.

Comment: Okay I didn't notice that, because the ***latest*** edit was just adding hyperlinks to Amber, NAMD, and GROMACS, but now I see that you made an edit slightly before that, which was more substantial.

Answer (score 1):

I got a clue from the comments of Anon.

[image]

A bond is present when the distance between two atoms is lower than the sum of the Van der Waals radii of the two atoms.

Van der Waals radii are typically looked up from a preexisting table, not calculated. We can find such tables in chemical reference books or online.

For instance, [**here is a link**](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/an-der-Waals-radii-of-atoms_tbl2_40906835) that supplies the following Van der Waals radii table:

[image]

---

**Please note that**

MD simulation software like [Amber](http://amber.manchester.ac.uk/), [NAMD](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/namd/namd-tutorial-unix-html/node25.html), [GROMACS](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/reference-manual/topologies/parameter-files.html), etc. use parameter-topology files to supply such information.

These files are the results of long-term experimentation and testing for decades.

Therefore, it is not a good idea for the new/learner/beginner/hobby MD simulation software developers to try to compute bond information themselves.

Comment: Determining whether two atoms are bonded isn't really challenging, although there are corner cases in PDB files (e.g., partial occupancy and atoms with alternate locations). The challenging part is figuring out bond orders just from the connectivity. But +1 in using RDKit or Open Babel. :-)

Comment: The edit on the MD software has nothing to do with the question posted. One thing is to know the connectivity. A completely different problem is to describe the PES of a molecule with a set of selected internal coordinates, with associated functions and parameters. I think you are a bit confused on what you want to know, so if you clarify your point we can probably help you.

Comment: @Anon, When I first wrote the question, my intension was to compute energy on the basis of bond information obtained from a PDB file so that I can perform MD simulation of proteins using an MD simulation software that I wrote in C++.

Comment: @Anon, When I was not finding a proper answer in MatterModeling.SE, I talked to a professor. He told me about parameter and topology files. he also told me that this is impossible to compute bond information from PDB file alone.

Comment: @Anon, What I understand now is that, your comment might have some degree of truth in it; but, trying to compute bond information from PDB file is not a practical idea. Besides, I found RDkit and OpenBabel too complex to get used to in a short time.

Comment: @Anon, Now, it is up to you what you want to write in that Community Wiki.